# Bytes.startswith gives two different answer when checking bytes from an python image download

Tags: python, image, byte, bytesio

Reading bytes gives conflicting results

```
    bytes_file = BytesIO(requests.get(source_url).content)

    accepted_start_bytes = {
    "jpeg": b'\xFF\xD8\xFF',
    "png":  b'\x89\x50\x4E\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A',
    }


    print( bytes_file.read().startswith(accepted_start_bytes['jpeg']))

    print( [bytes_file.read().startswith(accepted_start_bytes['jpeg'])])
```

has the output of

```
>>> True
>>> False
```

I would think these should be the same...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Turns out that you need to seek the zero position of the file before you read it, due to how the file is read.

The code should be

```
bytes_file = BytesIO(requests.get(source_url).content)

accepted_start_bytes = {
"jpeg": b'\xFF\xD8\xFF',
"png":  b'\x89\x50\x4E\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A',
}

bytes_file.seek(0)
print( bytes_file.read().startswith(accepted_start_bytes['jpeg']))
bytes_file.seek(0)
print( [bytes_file.read().startswith(accepted_start_bytes['jpeg'])])
```

This gets a result of

```
>>> True
>>> True
```